# How do I block everyone except for specific computers from everything except web browsing?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have recently acquired Google Fiber.  I live in a poorer neighborhood and would like to provide internet service to everyone nearby at no cost.  Currently, I only have the standard Fiber router / modem combination.  I would like to block access to everything except basic web browsing for every device except for my two phones and my laptop.

Would I be able to do this with the google router or would I need to purchase an additional router to setup security rules without a password?

Comment: That really depends on the functionality of the Google router as well as  the level of customization allowed by them on that router.  Without knowing these it's difficult to answer your question.

Comment: In almost all cases where you're providing a "more than SoHo" solution then you should, really, invest in a proper solution... even something like re-purposing an old PC and turn it into a proxy server so you can manage and monitor connections and, more importantly, provide the granular rules you desire...

Comment: set up and require that clients use a proxy server. that way you can control what connections are allowed.

Comment: You also need to take care as you would then be responsible for any illegal activities performed on your connection.

Comment: You'd also need to check that your customer agreement with Google as an ISP even allows you to share it in that way at all. Most wouldn't.

Comment: you should be able to connected a second wireless router to your main one, switch off the DHCP server on it, set a static IP address then block all ports except port 80 and 443.

Answer (score 0):

Legally: Its 99% sure you cant do this, I'd be dumbfounded if the Google Terms of Service allow you do it.

Technically: You need to invest in a captive portal to use for the open side. You could maintain the google router for your own access and not be limited, but the open AP would be.

Additionally you'd probably want to put up an omni directional antenna on the corner of the house to get any kind of decent coverage.